# OWLAPI slow calculating disjoint axioms

Tags: owl-api

*My goal*: find the disjoint axioms (asserted and inferred) in an ontology which contains around 5000 axioms.

*My code:*

```
for (OWLClass clazz1 : ontology.getClassesInSignature()) {
    for (OWLClass clazz2 : ontology.getClassesInSignature()) {
        OWLAxiom axiom = MyModel.factory.getOWLDisjointClassesAxiom(clazz2, clazz1);
            if(  !(ontology.containsAxiom(axiom)) && reasoner.isEntailed(axiom))
            {
                System.out.println(clazz2.toString() + " disjoint with " + clazz1.toString());
            }
```

*The problem*: the execution time is extremely slow, I'd say eternal. Even if I reduce the number of comparison with some if statement, the situation is still the same.

Protege seems to be very quick to compute those inferred axioms and it's based on the same API I am using (OWLAPI). So, am I in the wrong approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Profiling the code will very likely reveal that the slow part is

```
reasoner.isEntailed(axiom)
```

This form requires the reasoner to recompute entailments for each class pair, including the pairs where `clazz1` and `clazz2` are equal (you might want to skip that).

Alternatively, you can iterate through the classes in signature once and use the reasoner to get all disjoint classes:

```
Set<OWLClass> visited=new HashSet<>();
for (OWLClass c: ontology.getClassesInSignature()) {
  if (visited.add(c)) {
    NodeSet set = reasoner.getDisjointClasses(c);
    for (Node node: set.getNodes()) {
        System.out.println("Disjoint with "+c+": "+node);
        visited.addAll(node.getEntities());
    }
  }
}
```

Worst case scenario, this will make one reasoner call per class (because no class is disjoint). Best case scenario, all classes are disjoint or equivalent to another class, so only one reasoner call is required.

Comment: Thank you very much, very efficient solution!
The execution time is now around 700ms. Despite this, I'm a bit worried because in Protégé with the same reasoner (Fact++ 1.6.5) and the same ontology, the execution time is around 300ms and it shows everything (hierarchy, equivalent, disjointness ecc.).
My question is: is OWLAPI slower and Protégé optimized, or I have the possibility to reach the same performance as Protégé?
Many thanks.

Comment: Difficult to tell, there's nothing protégé does that is not done through the OWLReasoner interface. You can check the settings on reasoner config in protégé to check if there are precomputed inferences set - those would count in the reasoner initialisation rather than execution time.

Comment: I checked and there are no precomputed inferences in the config. Probably the problem is somewhere else, but still it holds good performance. May I ask just one last question? From the code above, is there a way to "filter" only the inferred axioms insted of taking also the asserted?
Thanks again for the help!

Comment: You can get the asserted disjoint axioms with ontology.getAxioms(AxiomType.DISJOINT_CLASSES)